# What does information-status mean in linguistics?

Tags: terminology, information-structure

The phrase information-status is used repdeatly in the article "Definiteness and Information-status in Hindi", Baldridge, 1996, but what does it mean? Could someone explain it simply/ say where I could find a simple explanation?

Comment: It's explained in the second paragraph of [the article itself](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~jason2/papers/hindidef.htm). What about the explanation isn't clear to you?

Comment: He explains it:  The information-status of a given noun is the speaker's specification to his/her audience as to where the entity which that noun refers to originated-directly from the speaker's world model; from the current situation; from what is thought to be mutually known; from the discourse itself; or from what may be inferred about something in the discourse.//This article is about what information determiners provide. The Hindi ones works differently than English or Spanish as there is ONLY one in Hindi. If I say to you: The dog on the porch. that is definite,

Comment: I mean, that explanation in the paragraph is very non intuitive and confusing to me. Perhaps because I don't know much linguistics @Lambie

Comment: It might help you to look up an introductory text/book on information structure/pragmatics. I've read Lambrecht's book which I found helpful, but that was in my 4th year of university linguistics. I'm not sure if there's something more accessible for those who are new to linguistics.

Comment: I'll check it out @curiousdannii

Comment: Maybe look at https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Pragmatic-Structures-in-Aymara-Homola-Coler/fc8d6bf2754eb925fd18fffaf2c69b2ba961af66, they explain what information structure is and how it’s related to pragmatics.

Comment: This is not about knowing "a lot about linguistics". He says this: Cross-linguistic evidence suggests that Prince's (1981) taxonomy of Assumed Familiarity is a more useful way of conceptualizing the information-status of discourse entities than article-driven, definite vs. indefinite approaches. This idea is easily found: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Assumed-familiarity-Source-Prince-E-F-1981-Towards-a-taxonomy-of-given-new_fig1_280570167 You have to look stuff up.